# is it possible to limit the number of displayed results by "ng-repeat" by starting the loop from some index and ending it at some another

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to implement this code

```
a[10];

for(int i=3;i<7;i++)

    a[i]
```

is it possible to implement such type of loop using ng-repeat

Comment: i know about limitTo but still the problem to set explicit start point remain intact!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (even if it is ugly imho):

```
<div ng-repeat="int in ints | limitTo: -7 | limitTo: 4">
    {{ int }} at {{ $index }}
</div>
```

[example with numbers](http://jsfiddle.net/z0vrhxqq/1/)

[example with 'stuffs'](http://jsfiddle.net/udb3pnhc/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Angular filters are fancy, but you don't need them for this particular use case because plain javascript `Array.prototype.slice` do exactly what you want:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <!-- $scope.ints = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] -->
    <div ng-repeat="int in ints.slice(3, 7)">
        {{ int }} at {{ $index }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Result:

```
3 at 0
4 at 1
5 at 2
6 at 3
```

[See it in action.](https://jsfiddle.net/4ogdtb2t/)

Answer (score 0):

limitTo takes an optional second parameter...

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo